# Sanitize SQL with RegExp

Tags: sql, regex

I have a text box in a project where user can write database queries, but I nedd to prevent statements like `DELETE`, `DROP` or use of comments (`/* */`, `--`) or semicolon `;`.

I'm using the folowing RegExp to check the query. It must math only valid statments.

```
/^(?!.*\-\-)(?!.*\/\*)(?!.*\*\/)(?!.*;)(?!.*CREATE)(?!.*DROP)(?!.*ALTER)(?!.*UPDATE)(?!.*DELETE).*$/
```

The RegExp is working fine, but it's not matching also line breaks and carriage returns (`\n`, `\r`), which should be permited.

How can I update the RegExp to allow `\n` and `\r`?

Comment: In witch language ? You can try to use the DOT-ALL modifier.

Comment: You could just run the statements under an account with correct DDL/DML  permissions

Comment: I think you would be better off by creating a user with just the minimum possible privileges. All DBMSs provide you with an extensive list of privileges that you can grant to users. Ex: [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html), [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-priv.html).

Comment: @AlexK. Yeah, it's just a precaution for if someone set send to production withou proper database configuration.

Comment: @FabSa **PCRE** (actualy, PHP `preg_match()`).

Comment: @SamuraiDio See http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php (PCRE_DOTALL).

Comment: @FabSa Thanks. The `PCRE_DOTALL` modifier did the trick. Would you please answer the question, just for me close it?

Comment: @SamuraiDio I juste see your comment now, sad, I miss 7 points for 1k+ ;) Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@FabSa gave me the answer.

The trick is just set the [`PCRE_DOTALL` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), as I'm using PHP _`preg_match()`. This does make a dot (`.`) metacharacter matches all characters, incluind newline (`\n`).

So, the final regex is as folows:

```
/^(?!.*\-\-)(?!.*\/\*)(?!.*\*\/)(?!.*;)(?!.*CREATE)(?!.*DROP)(?!.*ALTER)(?!.*UPDATE)(?!.*DELETE).*$/s
```